# Сделать url

Tags: url, .htaccess, php

Кто хорошо знает `htaccess`? Помогите, пожалуйста,
нужно сделать такой примерно урл `products/cat/1`
Отдельно `products` работает, отдельно `cat-1` тоже. 
но если поставить слэш не работает
Сам урл такой `index.php?url=products&cat=1`
по сути мне нужна подсказка как сделать правиильно рерайт со слэшем не теряя при этом подключаемые файлы цсс и яваскрипт

Comment: то есть даже если поставить RewriteRule ^cat/([0-9]{1,2})$ все раавно не работает и плюс умирают css

Comment: `RewriteBase /` стоит?

Comment: да и RewriteEngine On тоже есть и все работает если слэш заменять только вот с ним не работает

Comment: аа RewriteBase нету а это иммет значение в данном вопросе?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/cat/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?url=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

Comment: работает друг но 2 косяка 1  все стили опять не подключаются 2 после нажатия на ссылку урл дублируется но про это писали на каком то сайте наверно сработает
но все равно спасибо!

Comment: Стили у вас слетают так как пути в html относительные. Для таких вещей существует тэг <base href="ссылка на сайт"></base> тогда браузер будет понимать что получая ваши CSS надо добавлять ссылку из base. В основном делают это следующим образом

<html><head><base href="/">...</base><body>...</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?url=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

Поправка. Первый раз забыл cat написать.
`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/cat/([^/]*)$ /index.php?url=$1&cat=$2 [L]`

Путь к css пишете абсолютный или относительный? Собака в этом.

Comment: не работает переходит на несуществующую страницу но все равно спасибо за то что откликнулись!